# Command Prompt set UTF8 not working after opening specific directory

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to automate opening up PSQL (PostgreSQL command prompt). I've got the batch program opening the correct directory however I'm not sure how to get it to run the command to switch to UTF8 mode? Here is what I currently have...

```
start cmd /k "cd C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\PostgreSQL 9.3 x64\bin"

run chcp 65001
```

Comment: definitely try changing the font from raster to lucida console, as that might support more. see if that works. Then also try cmd /u

Comment: `run chcp 65001` results to an error for me, so use `chcp 65001` or `mode con: cp select=65001`. Remember [there is still very limited support for unicode in the CMD shell](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)